# How to fetch data from Component with Supabase & Auth Helpers Sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

I have an input inside a component in Svelte. It is part of series of steps using svelte-stepper. I need the user to enter their organizationID into an input field and then I want to see if that value exists in the database.

```
// Component.svelte
import type { PageData } from './$types';
    export let data: PageData;
    async function findFirm() {
        console.log('QUERYING FIRM DATABASE');
        const { data: firm, error } = await data.supabase
            .from('firms')
            .select('id, firm_name,firm_address')
            .eq('id', firmPassword);
        if (firm) {
            const [fetchedUser] = firm;
            try {
                firmID.set(fetchedUser.id);
                firmName.set(fetchedUser.firm_name);
                firmAddress.set(fetchedUser.firm_address);
                completeYourProfile.set(fetchedUser.complete_your_profile);
                buildYourTeam.set(fetchedUser.build_your_team);
                firmComplete.set(fetchedUser.firm_complete);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

            console.log('FIRM FETCHED');
            invalidPassword = false;
            firmFound = true;
        } else {
            console.log('THERE WAS AN ERROR FETCHING FROM FIRM DATABASE');
            invalidPassword = true;
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Whenever I try and run this I get this error:

```
Component.svelte:44 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'supabase')
    at HTMLInputElement.findFirm
```

I am using Auth Helpers for Sveltekit and I do not know how to invoke a fetch in a +page.svelte from a component.

Here is a diagram of what I am trying to do in 2 different ways:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple reactive statement with a store being passed in a function's argument worked.

```
//+page.svelte
    $: {
        yourFunction($yourStore);
    }
```

Edit the store in the component and the function will run every time the store value is changed.